# Редактирование таблицы excel

Tags: c#, excel

Подскажите, как можно на c# **редактировать** таблицу? То есть, имеется xlsx файл с готовой таблицей. И на c# нужно как-то эту таблицу отредактировать и записать обратно (при этом нужна возможность работать с цветами ячеек и их объедением). Какие библиотеки подойдут?

Comment: NPOI и платные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть много вариантов:

1. Office.Interop. Обладает всей необходимой функциональностью, но крайне медленный и на машине должен стоять пакет Office.
2. Работать с OpenXML. Скачать SDK для .NET и работать с вашей XML. Есть все необходимые возможности. Из минусов- это то, что вас никто за ручку вести не будет и нужно знать какие узлы и где менять.
3. Использовать библиотеку, которая является оберткой над OpenXML, например EpPlus. Все интуитивно понятно, быстро.

Comment: `Office.Interop` не такой уж и медленный

Comment: @slippyk, медленный если с Range работать...

Comment: это если по одному элементу перебирать, а если массив копировать в `range` то быстро

Comment: @slippyk, не знаю... Например, я не нашел в гугле решений, как таблицу Word'а, которая на 300 страниц быстро прочитать. Она читалась у меня в районе часа через интеропт, а если через OpenXML, то за несколько секунд.